# R - Match a vector of strings against itself

Tags: r, matrix, matching

so I have a vector of strings with about 35000 entries and I want to use the following function (RecordLinkage::levenshteinSim) to match each string against everyother string and then have a matrix with all the results. Telling me how similar each string is to every other one.

How do I do this ? 
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A matrix $35000 \times 35000$ might be a bit too large for many machines, even if it suffices to store the upper or lower triangle.

If you have oodles of memory and you can store such a large matrix, something like this might work:

```
> a <- 1:4
> myfun <- function(x,y) { x+y }
> outer(a,a, FUN=myfun)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    3    4    5
[2,]    3    4    5    6
[3,]    4    5    6    7
[4,]    5    6    7    8
```

In place of `a` you might give your vector of strings and in place of `myfun` the function which calculates distances among strings.

And if that fails, you can always loop.

Comment: hey, would you also happen to know how to only store the lower triangle?

Comment: You have function 'as.dist' which will take an object of type matrix and store in efficiently: but you still have to create the matrix beforehand.

Comment: Also, you may have a look at package 'Matrix' which provides classes for dense and sparse matrices, including classes dsyMatrix and dtpMatrix which store symmetric and general triangular matrices. Do note that you still have a large object, storing one triangle only cuts storage requirement by half.

Comment: thank you, after doing some quick calculations cutting it in half would still be too much.

would it lower storage requirements if i were to put in a treshhold ? so that the function only makes an entry into the matrix if the value e.g. would e above 0.8 ? 
Or does 'NA' use as much space ?

Comment: If you are content with storing only a subset of distances, then look at sparse matrices in the package 'Matrix'. Then the storage is proportional to the number of stored distances. If, say, only 2% are above your desired threshold, the savings are significant w.r.t. a solution using a dense matrix mostly populated with NA's.